# Помогите создать JSON

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Необходимо создать вот такой json

```
"pokaznik_10_2017" : {
  "1" : {
    "pokaznikVal" : ""
  },
  "2" : {
    "pokaznikVal" : ""
  }
  ....
  ,
  "368" : {
    "pokaznikVal" : ""
  }
}
```

Comment: такой JSON создать невозможно, потому что `....` в середине - это синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: А в чём проблема то?

Comment: @Grundy Думаю, `....` это что-то вроде "etc."

Comment: нужно создать от 1 до 368. чтоб в ручную не копировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(let i = 1; i < 369; i++){
    myObject[i] = {
         pokaznikVal: myValue
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуй запустить свой первый пример

Comment: первый пример не рабочий, второй работает. моя ошибка

Comment: отлично, спасибо) а как мне его еще вывести чтоб скопировать?

Comment: _первый пример не рабочий_ - тогда не стоит его оставлять в ответе, раз он все равно нерабочий

Comment: console.log(myObject)

Comment: @ЕгорКулик cоnsole.log возвращает вот так Object {1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object, 10..... а нужно в таком формате как в вопросе

Comment: console.log(myObject.toJSON)

Comment: @olezha, [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)